# how to minify a whole folder content using grunt.js

Tags: javascript, client-server, gruntjs

Instead of mention every `js` seperatly,
is this the way to minify and concatinate a whole js folder?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
  min: {
    dist: {
      src: ['scripts/*.js'],
      dest: 'dist/built.min.js'
    }
  }
});

};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to minify multiple Javascript files in a folder with UglifyJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008472/how-to-minify-multiple-javascript-files-in-a-folder-with-uglifyjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct if you only want to concatenate and minify all `.js` files in the `scripts` directory one level deep.

For example, if `scripts/` contains `a.js` and `b.js` and the `foo/` directory, you'd get the concatenation and minified result of `a.js` + `b.js` but nothing in the `foo/` directory.

What if you want to get everything in the `foo/` directory (and all other nested directories) as well? Change the expression from `['scripts/*.js']` to `['scripts/**/*.js']` -- or any minimatch expression:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/api_file.md#gruntfileexpand

You're able to use any minimatch expression since the grunt `min` task uses the `expandFiles` function:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/tasks/min.js#L21

The downside to using a minimatch expression with this task is it's hard to understand *what order* the files will be concatenated in, which is often very important. Be careful if this matters.

Also, please note that a new version of grunt (`0.4`) is coming out very soon. This will make this answer obsolete, as the `min` task has been changed in `0.4` (but will still support minimatch expression).

Answer (score 0):

If your folder consist only js files you are right but if your folder have nested folders such as, `foo` is our main js folder in which we have another nested folder `loo` and inside it we also have some js files such as :

```
 foo:
        mu.js
        su.js
        loo:
              ku.js
              wu.js
```

In this case you have to modify your code in such manner :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
  min: {
    dist: {
      src:  'foo/**/*.js',
      dest: 'dist/foo.min.js'
    }
  }
});

};
```

by doing in such a way you can minimize your all js files of `foo` folder even nested folder files too. I suggest cocat js files before minimizing.