# Combine multiple javascript files with bower

Tags: javascript, bower

I'm looking into using Bower with my project (more specifically, django-bower), and I was curious if bower has the ability to combine multiple javascript files into one file when pushing to production.

In other words it would take:

- jquery.min.js
- angular.min.js
- something_else.js
- another_thing.js

and produce one file that the user loads: everything.js

In reality we have upwards of 20-30 js files, which is why this would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).  It takes your Node requires and compiles them into a single JS file that can be included in your HTML.  Ex main.js:

```
var JQuery = require('jquery');
var Angular = require('Angular');
require('./something_else');
require('./another_thing');
```

Browserify your dependency chain...

```
browserify main.js > compiled.js
```

Include in your HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="compiled.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

`Bower` is a package manager. I think what you're looking for is [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

See how to [minify multiple js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008472/how-to-minify-multiple-javascript-files-in-a-folder-with-uglifyjs/17008710#17008710) using `grunt`.