# Unable to minify Vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, minify

I have a Vue.js Application with the following excerpt of code:

```js
(function() {
    initApp();
})();

function initApp() {
    window.myApp = new Vue({
        el: '#wrapper',
        data() {
  return {
  somedata: []
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
```

When I try to minify it, it fails with the error `Error : Unexpected token: punc (()` but the application runs successfully. I'm not sure why?

Comment: Which minifier are you using? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I've tried using the jscompress.com and javascript-minifier.com online tools. I will attempt to create a minimal example.

Comment: I highly recommend automating these kinds of task with a node tasks runner like _Gulp_, _Grunt_ or _Webpack_ for even much more features and use a minifier like [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that these websites both use Uglify.

Comment: But you don't have control over which version, and you have to do it manually every time you make a release, etc.

Comment: I've updated the example to be a little more complete. Yep, I just do it manually at the moment but releases are not very frequent.

Comment: Try: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: @StupidKid, that did the trick. Is it because Uglify does not support ES6?

Comment: I truly am Happy that did the trick But I have no idea I just searched for vuejs minifier on google :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those compressors simply only support an old version of JavaScript. Their support is restricted to at most ES5. To make your code work, convert it:

```
(function() {
    initApp();
})();

function initApp() {
    window.myApp = new Vue({
        el: '#wrapper',
        data: function() { // changed this line
            return {
                somedata: []
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And it should compress.

#### Details:

[They use `uglify-js: "^3.3.10"`](https://github.com/circlecell/jscompress.com/blob/master/package.json#L67), that is known for [not supporting ES6(`uglify-es` does)](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/659#issuecomment-302954977) .

From [their repo](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/blob/v3.3.20/README.md#uglifyjs-3) (emphasis mine):

> ## UglifyJS 3
>
> UglifyJS is a JavaScript parser, minifier, compressor and beautifier
>   toolkit.
>
> Note:
>
> - (...)
> - `uglify-js` **only supports JavaScript (ECMAScript 5)**.
> - To minify ECMAScript 2015 or above, transpile using tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 1):

## Your compressor isn’t ES6 compliant

You’re getting that error because, like [pacdcjunior's said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49724401/3965565), your compressor isn’t ES6 compliant. (I got your same error when I switched from jQuery to Vue.js—using ES6 syntax.)

**Solution: Use [Terser](https://github.com/terser-js/terser) instead.**

It’s ES6 compliant, in active development (at the time of writing), and is a direct replacement for [Uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

### Bonus: How to minify lots of files in one pass with Terser

You can minify a *single* file in Terser from the command line like this:

$ `terser file.js -m -o file.min.js`

But if you have a load of files to minify in one go, that will be tedious. I found [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23292374/3965565) and modified it just a little. Add this to your .bash_profile:

`alias renderjs='rm *.min.js; for f in *.js; do short=${f%.js}; terser $f -m -o $short.min.js; done'`

Navigate to your `js` directory and run `renderjs`. Now *all* your `*.js` files have a minified version. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the compiled js file (app.js)? If that case you just compile for production "npm run production".